# es6 use ${} for multiple state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For some reason I have to do this

```
for(let i=0;i<=6;i++){
    price.push({
        min_price: `this.state.special_${i}_min`,
        max_price: `this.state.special_${i}_max`
    });
}
```

But it's not what I expect, it doesn't work, it became string instead of getting the value of my states.

Answer (score 5):

You are just assigning the string to those properties. Try using square brackets.

```
price.push({
    min_price: this.state[`special_${i}_min`],
    max_price: this.state[`special_${i}_max`]
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can write like this in es6:

```
for(let i=0;i<=6;i++){
    price.push({
        min_price: this.state[`special_${i}_min`],
        max_price: this.state[`special_${i}_max`],
    });
}
```

for es5:

```
for(let i=0;i<=6;i++){
    price.push({
        min_price: this.state["special_"+i+"_min"],
        max_price: this.state["special_"+i+"_max"],
    });
}
```